# How to expose lighting record edit form on salesforce site

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

```html
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Financial_Entity_AC_Detail__c" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
    <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"> </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Financial_Entity__c" value={currentPayeId} filter={filter}  disabled={isPayeeLookupDisabled}> </lightning-input-field>

    <lightning-input-field field-name="Bank_Account_Number__c"> </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Bank_Name__c"> </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Branch_Name__c"> </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="IFSC_Code__c"> </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Task_ID__c" disabled value={taskId}> </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Verification_Type__c"> </lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-button variant="destructive-text" label="Back" title="Back to payee" onclick={backToPayee} class="slds-m-right_meduim" disabled={isbackToPayeeDisabled}></lightning-button>

    <lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" variant="brand">
    </lightning-button>

</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

tried this standard salesforce lighting-record-edit-form  to use on site but getting error the
record is not createable

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions of the running user? What do you mean by "site", the old school Visualforce Sites, newer Digital Experiences (formerly known as customer portal, customer community)? Is this supposed to be used by a logged in user or unauthenticated.

Find your community user's Profile (or permission sets) and check if there's right to Create these objects (and Edit on the fields used in the form). If it's not a real logged in user - you can still hunt down the `{Site Name} Guest User` hidden Profile: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_config_guest_user_profile.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks eyescream for your response im talking about  the old school Visualforce Sites

Comment: Setup -> User Interface -> Sites -> find the right name -> there should be [Public Access  Settings] button. Or run `select id, name from profile where UserLicense.Name = 'Guest User License'`, select `{site name} Profile` you need, copy the ID. then "url hack", go to any "normal" profile and paste that Id to address bar, just watch out for that "%2F" sign `/lightning/setup/EnhancedProfiles/page?address=%2F00e5J000000Ybg9QAC`